# SQL Left Join - Multiple Rows in Right Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, join

I am trying to make PHP / MySQL Search Form. When a user wants to search he need to fill 3 input fields: **FromDate**, **ToDate** and **SucategoryID**.

There are 2 tables: **Items and ItemsBlockDates**
In Table Items, there is info about the item and it is identified by ID.
In Table ItemBlockDates, there is info about a period when Item will not be displayed in search results. It contains: **ItemID, FromDate**, and **Date** fields. Also, there is a possibility to define more than one Block Date for one item.

Now, I want to select all Items where FromDate and To Date inputs does not match with any of rows in ItemsBlockDates with same ItemID.

I wrote a query, but there is a problem:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Items 
LEFT JOIN ItemBlockDates ON Items.ID = ItemBlockDates.ItemID 
WHERE Items.SubcategoryID = :SubcategoryID   
  AND ItemBlockDates.FromDate NOT BETWEEN CAST(:FromDate AS DATETIME) AND CAST(:ToDate AS DATETIME)
```

When I run this query it does not display Items where Block Dates are not set, also it displays items where more than one Block Date is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to select all Items where FromDate and To Date inputs does not
>   match with any of rows in `ItemsBlockDates` with same ItemID.

To me, this suggests `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM Items i
WHERE i.SubcategoryID = :SubcategoryID AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ItemBlockDates ibd
                  WHERE i.ID = ibd.ItemID AND
                        ibd.FromDate BETWEEN CAST(:FromDate AS DATETIME) AND CAST(:ToDate AS DATETIME)
                 );
```

If you are passing in a parameter, I'm not sure why you need to convert to a `DATETIME`.  You should be able to pass it in with the correct type.